# Failed to read x bytes from socket within x milliseconds

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Can anyone explain what this means and what I can do about it?

```
Failed to read 4 bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds
```

It happenes again and again during bulk writes to MongoDB with the new PHP driver for MongoDB. The full error message was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException' with message 'Failed to
send "insert" command with database "bibliographic": Failed to read 4 bytes
from socket within 300000 milliseconds.' in /var/www/html/bms/functions.php:143
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/bms/functions.php(143):
MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeBulkWrite('bibliographic.d...',
Object(MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite)) #1 /var/www/html/bms/webpages/import.php(13):
parseMARC21XMLfile('../../DNB-Titel...', 'mongodb', '', '', '',
'bibliographic.d...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/bms/functions.php on
line 143
```

I tried to make the script slower with PHP's `usleep()` function which seemed to "solve" the problem. But the script is to slow then.. Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Yes, but by completely reinstalling MongoDB and rewriting my script.. So I have no idea what I did.. Should I delete this post or do you have the same problem?

Comment: I was having the same issue. I was using MongoDB verion 3.2.9 on Ubuntu 14.04. Reinstalled MongoDB version 3.2.8 and things are going like charm.

Comment: I was also using Ubuntu 14.04 that time.

Comment: Same problem here